# Unsolved references using Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, debugging, kotlin

New to programming and running into unsolved references in android studio

Tried everything to my limited knowledge which isn't much 
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: The above are the rules here. Post a clear problem statement, and the relevant code **as properly formatted text** in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you really need this one.

but you can try

`MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`

for `Manifest` make sure you have imported

```
import android.Manifest
```

and not `java.util.jar.Manifest`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the reference you're looking for is not [`MediaStore.Image.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

`MediaStore.Media` doesn't exist directly, check your documentation.